# Running keras model on colab TPU

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, tpu

I am currently trying to train a convolutional neural network **`CNN`** using Keras and the `Google Colab` GPU.
I found this [article](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/03/train-keras-model-20x-faster-tpu-free.html) that discussed the option to increase the training time that is needed to train the model. Since the current training on the **GPU** is very slow I tried to implement the method from the article. I have the following code:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.02)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
def create_train_subsets():
    X_train =[]
    y_train = []
    for i in range(80):
      cat = i+1
      path = 'train_set/by_cat/{}'.format(cat)
      for img in os.listdir(path):
        actual_image = Image.open(("train_set/by_cat/{}/{}".format(cat,img)))
        X_train.append(actual_image)
        y_train.append(cat)
    return X_train, y_train

# This address identifies the TPU we'll use when configuring TensorFlow.
x_train, y_train = create_train_subsets()
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))

history = tpu_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        epochs=20,
                        batch_size=128 * 8,
                        validation_split=0.2)

tpu_model.save_weights('./tpu_model.h5', overwrite=True)
# tpu_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128 * 8)
```

This code however gives back the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ConfigureDistributedTPU' used by node ConfigureDistributedTPU (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) with these attrs: [tpu_embedding_config="", is_global_init=false, embedding_config=""]
Registered devices: [CPU, XLA_CPU]
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[ConfigureDistributedTPU]]
```

I did an extensive search online but I can't seem to find any indication on what it means. Also, I am not understanding the process enough to figure out the exact meaning of the error myself.

Therefore, is there anybody out there that can help me understand what is wrong and maybe also knows a solution on how to solve this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First test if the TPU is working properly as a sanity check. Make a variable (tensor) `a` and another `b` and add them to get `c` in `tf`. Since, you know what `a`, `b` and `c` are, write a tf.function to test if `c` = `a` + `b`. If while running TPU, you get TRUE as a result, it means tensorflow is able to use TPU on Colab, which should be the case, but still it's better to check it first.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did get a message that it connected to the TPU in google collab. After some extra digging I assume the error has something to do with tensorflow and keras having a different model initiation which resulted in my keras model not being able to find the TPU. :) different problems now but not related to this error lol. Thnx for the pointer.